# Let $f$ be a nondecreasing function on $[1,\infty)$, $F(x)=\int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt, x \ge 1.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a nondecreasing function on $[1,\infty)$, and define

$$F(x)=\int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt, x \ge 1.$$

Prove that $f$ is bounded on $[1, \infty)$ if and only if $F/log$ is bounded on $[1, \infty)$.

I am having difficulty proving that if $F/log$ is bounded on $[1, \infty)$, then $f$ is bounded on $[1, \infty)$.

This is the work I've done so far.

First, consider the case where $f \le 0$ on $[1, \infty)$. Then since $f$ is nondecreasing, 
$$F(x)=\int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt \le f(x)\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt=f(x)logx,$$

so $|F/log|$ bounded implies |f| bounded.

Now let's assume there is some $b \gt 1$ s.t $f(b)=0$. And we only need to consider $x \ge b$ since the other case is the same as the previous one.

For $x \ge b$, $$F(x)=\int_1^b \frac{f(t)}{t}dt+\int_b^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt \le int_1^b \frac{f(t)}{t}dt+f(x)\int_b^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$

so $$\frac{F(x)}{logx} \le \frac{1}{logx} * \int_1^b \frac{f(t)}{t}dt + \frac{[logx-logb]}{logx}f(x)$$

However, from this inequality I only get a lower bound on $f$ so I can't show that $f$ is bounded.

How may I prove this result? I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F/\log $ is bounded on $[1,∞)  \Rightarrow f$  is bounded on $[1,∞)$:
We define $\tilde{f} (x)=f(x)-f(1)$. Then $\tilde{f}(x)$ is nonnegative and nondecreasing. Also we have$$
F(x)-f(1)\log x=\int_1^x \frac{\tilde{f}(t)}{t}dt,\,  x \ge 1.$$Suppose that $\tilde{f}(x)$ is unbounded. Then for any $M>0$, there is a $x_0$ such that $\tilde{f}(x)\ge M$ for all $x>x_0$. Since$$F(x)-f(1)\log x\ge \int_{x_0}^x \frac{\tilde{f}(t)}{t}dt\ge M\int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{t}dt=M(\log x-\log x_0),$$
we have for sufficiently large $x$$$\frac{F(x)}{\log x}-f(1)\ge M\left(1-\frac{\log x_0}{\log x}\right)\ge \frac{M}{2}.$$
This contradicts the fact that $F(x)/\log x$ is bounded since we can take arbitrary large $M$.

Comment: Excuse me, how did you get M/2 in the last part?

Comment: @mobzopi -- For sufficiently large $x$, $\frac{\log x_0}{\log x}<\frac{1}{2}$. Then $\left(1-\frac{\log x_0}{\log x}\right)>\frac{1}{2}$.